# Логика размещения дочерних блоков в HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, layout, поток-документа

Изучаю свойства `display: block`, `display: inline` и `display: inline-block`.

Когда верстаю элементы без дочерних элементов, то всё понятно, но сейчас возникла странность.

Почему дочерний блок во второй колонке сместился к низу колонок, в которых дочерних блоков больше?

```css
.column {
  display: inline-block;
}

.div1 {
  background: cyan;
}

.div2 {
  background: brown;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <div class="div1">div1</div>
  <div class="div2">div2</div>
</div>
<div class="column">
  <div class="div1">div1</div>
</div>
<div class="column">
  <div class="div1">div1</div>
  <div class="div2">div2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Потому что выравнивание идёт по базовой линии, это настраивается через vertical-align

Comment: Правильно ли я понял, что из-за свойства inline-block в родительском элементе, дочерние элементы выровнились подобно выравниванию заглавных и строчных букв в обычной строке?

Comment: Нет, дочерние элементы у вас никак не выравниваются и просто идут подряд сверху вниз как обычно принято для div. Выравниваются именно элементы column, у которых стоит inline-block

Comment: Да, точно. Рад тому, что вы грамотно объяснили, и что я сообразил.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Значение по умолчанию для свойства [vertical-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) равняется "baseline", когда Вы превращаете блочный элемент в [inline-block](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/display) то оно начинает к нему применяться.

Разницу я проиллюстрировал ниже:

[image: введите сюда описание]

Живой пример:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.example {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.column {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

.example.one .column {
  vertical-align: baseline; // значение по умолчанию
}

.example.two .column {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.example.three .column {
  vertical-align: top;
}

.div1 {
  background-color: orange;
}

.div2 {
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<div class="example one">
  <p>baseline<p>
  <small>значение по умолчанию</small>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="div1">div1</div>
    <div class="div2">div2</div>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <div class="div1">div1</div>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <div class="div1">div1</div>
    <div class="div2">div2</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="example two">
  <p>middle<p>
  <small>&nbsp;</small>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="div1">div1</div>
    <div class="div2">div2</div>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <div class="div1">div1</div>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <div class="div1">div1</div>
    <div class="div2">div2</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="example three">
  <p>top<p>
  <small>&nbsp;</small>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="div1">div1</div>
    <div class="div2">div2</div>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <div class="div1">div1</div>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <div class="div1">div1</div>
    <div class="div2">div2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Актуально ли использовать сегодня display block и position, вместо flex?

Comment: @Doofy, всегда актуально, мне кажется.. В прочем, всё зависит от задачи.