# Почему label для textarea отображается не сверху, а внизу?

Tags: html, css, выравнивание, поток-документа

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

fieldset {
  border: 4px solid green;
}

legend {
  background: yellow;
}

textarea {
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Личная информация</legend>
    <label for="1">Имя</label><input title="Введите свое имя" id="1" type="text" name="name"> <br>
    <label for="2">Email</label> <input id="2" type="email"> <br>
    <label for="3">Пароль</label> <input id="3" type="password">
    <br>
    <br>
    <label for="4">О себе </label> <textarea name="comment" id="4" cols="" rows=""></textarea>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Я уже расписывал это момент более подробно в вопросе [Логика размещения дочерних блоков в HTML/CSS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1158401/397819)

Все дело в свойстве [vertical-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align), для [inline элементов](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements) значение которого по умолчанию равняется "baseline".

Именно поэтому Вы видите что элемент `label` выровнен по нижнему краю относительно `textarea`.

Сейчас выровнено по верхнему краю:

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

fieldset {
  border: 4px solid green;
}

legend {
  background: yellow;
}

label {
  vertical-align: top;
}

textarea {
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Личная информация</legend>
    <label for="1">Имя</label><input title="Введите свое имя" id="1" type="text" name="name"> <br>
    <label for="2">Email</label> <input id="2" type="email"> <br>
    <label for="3">Пароль</label> <input id="3" type="password">
    <br>
    <br>
    <label for="4">О себе </label> <textarea name="comment" id="4" cols="" rows=""></textarea>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!